# Scala for-comprehension with Option and Some, wrapped by ReaderT

Tags: scala, typeclass, scala-cats, for-comprehension, subtyping

Here is an example that works fine:

```
  import cats.data.ReaderT
  import cats.instances.option._
  ...
  def f1:ReaderT[Option, Service, Int] =
    ReaderT(service => for {
      res <- Some(10)
    } yield res )
```

Here is an example that is not compiled:

```
  def f2:ReaderT[Option, Service, Int] =
    for {
      res <- ReaderT((_:Service) => Some(10))
    } yield res
```

I get the following error:

> Error:(53, 11) could not find implicit value for parameter F:
>   cats.Functor[Some]
>         res <- ReaderT((*:Service) => Some(10)) Error:(53, 11) not enough arguments for method map: (implicit F:
>   cats.Functor[Some])cats.data.Kleisli[Some,com.savdev.Service,Int].
>   Unspecified value parameter F.
>         res <- ReaderT((*:Service) => Some(10))

To fix the error in the 2nd example, I must return not `Some`, but `Option`, which is a parent for `Some`:

```
  def f2:ReaderT[Option, Service, Int] =
    for {
      res <- ReaderT((_:Service) => Option(10))
    } yield res
```

Can you please explain this? Why in the 1st example returning `Some`, but not `Option`, works fine. Why at the same time in the 2nd example, returning `Some` is not compiled? Is there an option for Scala compiler to compile cases, like in the 2nd example? Or other solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In the first case, it invokes `map` directly on `Some`, which is known to return an `Option` (ordinary polymorphism with subclass `Some` of `Option`), then it goes on to find `Functor[Option]`.
2. In the second case, the return type of your function is inferred to be `Some[Int]`,  and the compiler attempts to find an instance of `Functor[Some]` typeclass in order to invoke a method on `Reader` (ad-hoc polymorphism with typeclass `Functor`), but this fails, because there is no functor for `Some`.

The main problem is that `Some` isn't just a constructor of instances of type `Option` (as it would be in Haskell, for example), but it is actually a constructor of instances of (mostly useless) type `Some`, which sometimes messes up type inference / implicits resolution.

If you want to enforce that the resulting type is `Option[Int]`, use `Option(10)` to construct `Some` or `Option.empty` to construct `None`.

Comment: thank for such detailed explanation! I accepted your answer as a more detailed.

Comment: @Alexandr I focused more on explaining why the error occurs, whereas the other answer focused more on explaining how to avoid it. `10.some` is nice too.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
import cats.syntax.option._

def f2: ReaderT[Option, Service, Int] =
  for {
    res <- ReaderT((_: Service) => 10.some)
  } yield res
```

It's better to use `x.some` and `none` (or `none[X]`) instead of `Some(x)` and `None`. They have type `Option[X]` instead of `Some[X]` and `None.type`. This can improve type inference sometimes. Actually it's `Option` that is an instance of `Functor` and not `Some`.

Look at "Extension method constructors" in https://blog.softwaremill.com/9-tips-about-using-cats-in-scala-you-might-want-to-know-e1bafd365f88

In the first case you were just lucky that types were inferred properly.

Comment: `Some(10)` is of type `Some[Int]`, not `Option[Int]`. It's not because of luck, it's because the [map](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Some.html#map[B](f:A=%3EB):Option[B]) method returns `Option[B]`.

Comment: Well, it's a luck that "the map method returns Option[B]" :)

Comment: Yes, admittedly, it depends on subtlest changes in the order of for-comprehensions and `Reader`-constructor invocations, so for most practical purposes it's almost as if the right type is inferred only when one gets lucky :] My point was just that it's still kind-of deterministic and explainable from the API. Paraphrasing Einstein, "The Compiler does not play dice." :P